# In Angular, $state.go() is not executed immediately

Tags: angularjs, url, state

Given my code:

```
oneFunctionInController() {
    $state.go('newState')
    anotherFunctionInController()
}

anotherFunctionInController() {
    let url = $location.url()
    //do something based on url
}
```

the problem is that when `anotherFunctionInController()` is executed, the url I get is still the old url, not "newState"

what is the reason? any solution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
oneFunctionInController() {
$state.go('newState').then(function(){
     anotherFunctionInController();
  });
}
```